# Implementing onTouchListener for a TextView

Tags: android, textview, ontouchlistener

I am implementing `onTouchListener` in `MainActivity` and attribute an `OnTouchListener` to a Textview `tv`, but as running no message pop up when the screen is pressed.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener
{
    TextView tv;    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setOnTouchListener(this);
        tv.setText(R.string.hello);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onTouch",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running this in the emulator or on a device?

Comment: Thank you, I'm running this on my android pad and I'm using the AIDE compiler to execute it. It just won't give any feedback when I touch the screen.

Comment: @paxdiablo if you don't want to be bothered, why are you on SO?

Answer (score 3):

```
TextView lastTV= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastTvValue);

lastTV.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    //do stuff here
                    }

                Log.i("click text", "kakak");
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this n accept if agree

```
 tv.setOnTouchListener(new CustomTouchListener());

public class CustomTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {     
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    switch(motionEvent.getAction()){            
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Action you you want on finger down.
  Toast.makeText(this,"onTouch",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;          
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:             
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Action you you want on finger up
                break;
    } 
        return false;   
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but just now I wrote a Log.v() method in onTouch() and the device seems giving no notice to the touch event..Thanks any way...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, onTouchListener() sometimes only receives some user touch inputs. Can you make it an onClickListener() and see if the behavior resolves?

I compiled and ran your code and it works fine, by the way. Can you have onTouch() print a Log.v() message and make sure your onTouch() is being called?

Comment: Thank you, I tried Log.v() but no message has been printed, while when I was trying onClickListener() by setting up buttons messages came...I feel it's strange

Answer (score 0):

You have to @override onTouch method, try to remove implements onTouchListener and again write it import correct one, it will not work until you write

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event)
{
    Toast.makeText(this,"onTouch",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
}
```